# Remove window shadow/glow from Visual Studio 2012

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2012

I am using Window 7.  I have removed the shadows from my windows, but Visual Studio 2012 seems to ignore that setting and draws a shadow (or glow) anyway.  Is there a way to remove that shadow/glow?

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/06/22/improving-performance-by-changing-the-visual-experience-vstipenv0017.aspx):

> In some situations, you can improve your Visual Studio performance by changing your Visual Experience.  To change these settings just go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General -> Visual Experience:

Untick "Enable rich client visual experience" and the shadows should go away.

Comment: Unfortunately not, the glow backing window is still created.